# Ignore attributed and compare collections

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 Collections using `CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection`. 
Before this, I need to remove or ignore one attribute of one object collection, this attribute needs to be ignored or deleted, because it is filled in only one collection.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you could please rephrase the question or add additional information such as a code snippit that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the class of your element, override

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

in equals method, ignore the certain field/attribute check.

oh, don't forget overriding

```
public int hashCode()
```

too.